How to expose apache camel kafka metrics with spring boot 3
I am trying to expose apache camel kafka metrics like kafka.admin.client.*, kafka.consumer.* at /actuator/metrics endpoint.
But still my metrics are not visible in /actuator/metrics endpoint or /actuator/prometheus endpoint. Please help me figure out what am I missing here.
So far I have tried with the following dependencies:
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-starter:4.6.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-kafka-starter:4.6.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-observation-starter:4.0.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-micrometer-starter:4.4.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients'
    implementation 'io.prometheus:simpleclient_pushgateway:0.16.0'

}

I am using spring boot version 3.2.5. In my properties file I have following properties:
   camel.component.kafka.brokers= localhost:9092
    camel.component.kafka.group-id= kafka-grp1
    spring.jmx.enabled= true
    management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= *
    camel.component.metrics.enabled= true
    camel.component.metrics.metric-registry= prometheusMeterRegistry


And my routes definition is:
@Component
public class Routes extends RouteBuilder
{
    @Override
    public void configure(){

        from("kafka:bits-to-bytes-topic")
                .routeId("route1")
                .log("route1 hit")
                .to("kafka:bits-to-bytes-producer")
                ;
        from("kafka:bits-to-bytes-producer")
                .routeId("route2")
                .log("route2 hit")
                .to("kafka:bits-to-bytes-consumer")
        ;
    }
}


Hello @Snehal wagh, did you get a feedback/solution to your question ?
